# Exercise: Finding lowest possible mse in linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have a linear regression with the datapoints x and y, as well as the model ypred = a*x+b.
I needed to set a = 10 and calculate the MSE, which worked fine. But I am having trouble looping through the code by decreasing a by 0.1 until 0 and to check for the lowest possible MSE. I have to repeat the same thing for b, but that shouldn't be a problem once the first part is figured out. I am also only allowed to use numpy, pandas and a plotting library (I used matplotlib).

Here's what I tried so far:

```
x = [0., 0.05263158, 0.10526316, 0.15789474, 0.21052632,
       0.26315789, 0.31578947, 0.36842105, 0.42105263, 0.47368421,
       0.52631579, 0.57894737, 0.63157895, 0.68421053, 0.73684211,
       0.78947368, 0.84210526, 0.89473684, 0.94736842, 1.]
y = [0.49671415, 0.01963044, 0.96347801, 1.99671407, 0.39742557,
       0.55533673, 2.52658124, 1.87269789, 0.79368351, 1.96361268,
       1.11552968, 1.27111235, 2.13669911, 0.13935133, 0.48560848,
       1.80613352, 1.51348467, 2.99845786, 1.93408119, 1.5876963]

# Scatterplot
data.plot(kind ='scatter', x,y)

# finding predicted y values when slope is set to 10
a = 10 
b = 0

for y in x:
    ypred = a*x+b

print(ypred)

# calculating MSE
sum_of_value = 0
n = len(y)

for i in range(0,n):
    diff = y[i]-ypred[i] # difference between y and predicted y
    sqdiff = diff**2 # difference squared
    sum_of_value = sum_of_value+sqdiff # adding all the squared differences
MSE = sum_of_value/n # divide by number of observations

print(MSE) # output: [21.30649942]

## finding lowest possible MSE
while a > 0:
    a = a - 0.1
    for i in range(0,n):
        diff = y[i]-ypred[i] # difference between y and predicted y
        sqdiff = diff**2 # difference squared
        sum_of_value = sum_of_value+sqdiff # adding all the squared differences
    MSEa = sum_of_value/n
    if MSEa < MSE:
        print(a, MSEa)
    else:
        continue
```

There is no error but also no output - however, setting a = 9 and going through the beginning it already gives a smaller MSE. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't linear regression give you the minimum MSE automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Break your code into functions for easier use:

```
def MSE(y, ypred):
    return sum((act-pred)**2 for act, pred in zip(y, ypred))/len(y)

def predict(x, a, b):
    return [a*xi+b for xi in x]

results = dict()
for a in range(100, 0, -1):
    ypred = predict(x, a/10, 0)
    results[a/10] = MSE(y, ypred)

>>> min(results, key=results.get)
2.2
```

Separately, your code *does* throw an error. You haven't declared `ypred` as a list or array anywhere in your OP but you try to use `ypred[i]`.

Comment: whoops, the error is on me. i had the datapoints stored in a different way originally and just copied them here.

Comment: I get the two defined functions and I was thinking along the line of defining something but I couldn't really put it into code. And yours works perfectly, of course so thank you, really! I just need to break it down mentally for me: the results of the MSEs are stored as a dictionary in results, alright. What does the argument a/10 do exactly?

Comment: `range` only works on integer values. So going from 100 to 0 in steps of -1 would give you 100, 99, 98 etc. You divide by 10 to use 10, 9.9, 9.8 :)